# std::thread, start thread on `this' (from within the class itself)

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to create a class which starts a thread-instance of a one of its member methods.
When I do in main:

```
test myinstance;
std::thread mythread(myinstance);
```

then things compile. But using the following construction:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <thread>

class test
{
        std::thread *pt;
public:
        test()
        {
                pt = new std::thread(this);
        }

        void operator()() const
        {
                printf("thread start\n");
                sleep(5);
                printf("thread end\n");
        }
};

int main(int arg, char *argv[])
{
        test ptest;
        sleep(10);

        return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

> folkert@here:~$ g++ -std=c++0x test.cpp In file included from
>   /usr/include/c++/4.6/thread:39:0,
>                    from test.cpp:3: /usr/include/c++/4.6/functional: In member function 'void std::_Bind_result<_Result, _Functor(_Bound_args
>   ...)>::__call(std::tuple<_Args ...>&&, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes
>   ...>, typename std::_Bind_result<_Result, _Functor(_Bound_args
>   ...)>::__enable_if_void<_Res>::type) [with _Res = void, _Args = {},
>   int ..._Indexes = {}, _Result = void, _Functor = test*, _Bound_args =
>   {}, typename std::_Bind_result<_Result, _Functor(_Bound_args
>   ...)>::__enable_if_void<_Res>::type = int]':
>   /usr/include/c++/4.6/functional:1378:24:   instantiated from
>   'std::_Bind_result<_Result, _Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::result_type
>   std::_Bind_result<_Result, _Functor(_Bound_args
>   ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {}, _Result = void,
>   _Functor = test*, _Bound_args = {}, std::_Bind_result<_Result, _Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::result_type = void]' /usr/include/c++/4.6/thread:117:13:   instantiated from 'void
>   std::thread::_Impl<_Callable>::_M_run() [with _Callable =
>   std::_Bind_result]' test.cpp:28:1:   instantiated from
>   here /usr/include/c++/4.6/functional:1287:4: error:
>   '((std::_Bind_result*)this)->std::_Bind_result::_M_f' cannot be used as a function

So my guess is that it won't work *this way*.
My question now is: how can I, using std::thread, let a class start a thread of one of its own methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of `std::thread`s constructors looks like this:

```
template<typename Callable>
    explicit thread(Callable func);
```

This requires you to pass something that is **callable**, that means it can be invoked with `operator()`.  What you're passing to your `std::thread` is not callable.

You cannot call `this`.  `this` is a pointer to the current object, it is not callable.

You need pass a member function or other function into your `std::thread` constructor.

You could also create a functor and pass that, as that is callable.

EDIT:  Just noticed have indeed overloaded `operator()`, to call it, you have do the follwowing:

```
  test t;
  std::thread my_thread(t); //invokes operator() on test.

//also remove this statement from your ctor:  pt = new std::thread(this);
```

Comment: Ah yes, Joachim Pileborg gave the answer!
If I do
    pt = new std::thread(*this);
or even
    pt = new std::thread(std::ref(*this));
then it compiles and runs!

Comment: @FolkertvanHeusden I must say that your construct of starting the thread within the ctor of your class, when you are using the overloaded `operator()` of that same class, is strange.

Comment: It seems like an attempt at emulating Java's (broken) thread API. As @Tony says, pass your callable object *to* the thread constructor. Don't put the thread inside the object it is supposed to call.

Comment: @jalf the idea of doing it like this, is that I don't want the user of my class to know how it is doing its stuff. If it is e.g. retrieving the remote data at invocation-time or in the background. And indeed, I might be a little bit java influenced :-)

Comment: Then split it in two classes. One containing the `thread` object, and one that is passed to the thread to be executed. The two are completely different areas of concern, and shouldn't be in the same class.

Answer (score 3):

Many fixes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

struct test
{
    void operator()() const
    {
        std::cout << "thread start\n";
        sleep(5);
        std::cout << "thread end\n";
    }
};

int main(int arg, char *argv[])
{
    std::thread pt(std::move(test()));

    pt.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Fixes

- separation of concerns (you can run `test` without a thread now, yay!)
- leaking the std::thread instance (memory + resource)
- not (deterministically) waiting for the thread to finish; this is UB even if you think you know that sleep will run longer
- Note how avoid the local/copy of ptest by doing a move. *Technically, `std::move` is redundant there, but I like things specific and you'd run into the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)*:

  ```
  std::thread pt((test()));
  ```

Comment: about that testing without a thread: I could add a parameter to the constructor like bool debug that doesn't start the thread and then manually call the worker-part (which would normally be in a thread). that way the information hiding is kept.

Comment: @FolkertvanHeusden since when is a the execution model information? It might be if the class was TaskManager or something. Right now, it is logically not the responsibility of a functor to decide where it executes, neither the responsability of a thread to decide what functionality to call...? That's not information hiding, that's promiscuous information sharing in my view

Comment: I hide the information how and when etc. things are retrieved. Well, maybe "information hiding" is not the correct name for it but what I'm trying to achieve is a black-box that retrieves something somehow without showing the outside world how things are done.

Comment: @FolkertvanHeusden: [async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async)/[future](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#std-async)? See also BM's blog http://www.corensic.com/Learn/Resources/ConcurrencyTutorialPartSix.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

pt = new std::thread( std::ref( *this ) );

Comment: Ooops, sorry saw my answer was a duplicate.